# How do I list all overloads for a particular Julia function?

Tags: list, julia, overloading

Julie allows multiple dispatch.

So we can overload `foo`:

```
foo(x::String)
foo(x::Float)
```

But how to retrieve all overloads currently in effect? (preferably together with filepath).

I was hoping for something like: `listoverloads("foo")`

Comment: yes, it's `methods(foo)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the command `methods(foo)`.